# unable to change data values when using $emit on an object in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Using `$emit` for communicating between `child` to `parent` component. I have a method in child component which trigger the $emit during diffferent stages of an `api` call. ie, before doing the api call I need to send few values to parent to disable some fields in parent. So using `$emit` to sent those values and it works successfully. But then when I try to call same $emit event after getting the result from api in same method it is not getting updated. The values are successfully getting emitted from child but in parent it only updates the first time.

Here is the parent component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="horizontal-fields">
      <input
        id="General_mobile"
        class="input-fied"
        name="mobileNumber"
        placeholder="Enter your mobile"
        type="number"
        autocomplete="new mobile"
        :disabled="otpInput.isVerifying"
      >
      <input @click.prevent="sendVerificationCode" value="sendotp" class="otp-btn" type="button">
    </div>

    <div v-if="otpInput.isOtpMode">
      <GeneralOtp
        :message="otpGeneratedMessage"
        :mobileNumber="this.mobileNumber"
        @handleComplete="handleCompleteOtp"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import GeneralOtp from "./GeneralOtp";

export default {
  name: "MobileVerification",
  components: {
    GeneralOtp
  },
  data() {
    return {
      mobileNumber: null,
      isValidMobile: null,
      buttonValue: "Send OTP",
      otpGeneratedMessage: null,
      otpInput: {
        isOtpMode: false,
        isVerifying: false,
        otpToken: null,
        currentVerifiedMobile: null
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async sendVerificationCode() {
      const { data } = await axios.get(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
      );
      if (data.userId) {
        this.otpGeneratedMessage = "some message from server";
        this.otpInput.isOtpMode = true; //to show otp input field(child component)
      }
    },
    handleCompleteOtp(value) {
      console.log("called");
      this.otpInput = value;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Here is the child component

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="!isVerifying">
      <input id="otp" class="input-fied" name="otpcode" placeholder="Enter your otp" type="number">
      <input @click.prevent="this.verifyOtp" value="buttonValue" class="otp-btn" type="button">
      <p style="margin-top: 2%">{{ message }}</p>
    </div>
    <div v-else="isVerifying">
      <p>Please wait</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  props: {
    message: {
      type: String,
      default: ""
    },
    mobileNumber: {
      type: String,
      default: null
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isVerifying: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async verifyOtp() {
      /* Disable inputs & show loading */
      this.isVerifying = true;
      this.respondToParent({
        otpToken: null,
        mobileNumber: this.mobileNumber,
        isVerifying: this.isVerifying,
        isOtpMode: false
      });

      /* Send verify request to server */
      const { data } = await axios.get(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
      );
      /* If success & valid hide in parent send verified flag to parent */
      /* If success & invalid otp show error */
      this.isVerifying = false;
      if (data.userId) {
        this.respondToParent({
          otpToken: "token from a success response",
          mobileNumber: this.mobileNumber,
          isVerifying: false,
          isOtpMode: false
        });
      } else {
        this.respondToParent({
          OtpToken: null,
          mobileNumber: this.mobileNumber,
          isVerifying: this.isVerifying,
          isOtpMode: false
        });
      }
      /* If error show retry button with error message */
    },

    respondToParent(value) {
      this.$emit("handleComplete", {
        otpToken: value.otpToken,
        mobileNumber: this.mobileNumber,
        isVerifying: value.isVerifying,
        isOtpMode: value.isOtpMode
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I cant figure out why its not getting updated the second time even though its getting called both times from child. Somehow managed to replicate the same on sandbox environment. 
[code in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxt-app-demo-20unr)

Comment: 1. Your codesandbox doesn't work. Can you fix it? 2. It's just a guess after a quick look but try changing `this.otpInput = value;` to `this.otpInput = { ...this.otpInput, ...value };`

Comment: @AdamOrlov the code still not working. I dont know why the codesandbox not working. Never used that before. The changes are not replicating in the preview of codesandbox. sorry for that.

Comment: @AdamOrlov the codesandbox is working now and the demo is exactly working web url https://20unr.sse.codesandbox.io/

Comment: did you fix it? as `console.log("called")` is getting called

Comment: @LawrenceCherone nope. even though its properly getting emitted the parent state is not changing on second call of the $emit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time you called `this.respondToParent`, it sets `otpInput.isOtpMode` to false, so `GeneralOtp` will not be rendered because you're using v-if:

```
<div v-if="otpInput.isOtpMode">
  <GeneralOtp
    :message="otpGeneratedMessage"
    :mobileNumber="this.mobileNumber"
    @handleComplete="handleCompleteOtp"
  />
</div>
```

You can check it will be called 2 times if you change your first `this.respondToParent` to

```
  this.respondToParent({
    otpToken: null,
    mobileNumber: this.mobileNumber,
    isVerifying: this.isVerifying,
    isOtpMode: true
  });
```

(Note that `isOtpMode: true`)

I think you should keep `isOtpMode` is true in the first call and use `isVerifying` to disable something in the parent component as you said.

Demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxt-app-demo-7b7dq)

Comment: It took me 2 days. I thought something related to state updation as am updating object in parent. Thanks a lot mate.